# Changing the axes of a contour plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a contour plot that is currently being plotted in the default x-y plane at some z location. I need to plot this in the y-z at some x-location. Does anyone know how to change the code below to allow this?

[Contour Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jijVo.png)

```
[~, one] = contourf(y_grid, z_grid, U_mean, 80,'edgecolor','none'); 
one.ContourZLevel = 8.125;
```

I tried a normal contour plot, and I was expecting the plot to appear in the y-z plane.

Comment: Most of the 3D plotting tools accept X, Y and Z coordinates, and some accept an additional C (colour) input... take a look at [`surf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) which is one such function - can you just use that instead?